# All properties available from a VSTO Outlook AdvancedSearch

Tags: vsto

I'm using VSTO with Outlook 2007, in c#. I can execute an Outlook.Application.AdvancedSearch(), and get a table. I want to select the columns to access from the table using Outlook.Table.Columns.Add(). I can't seem to find a complete list of property names that I can pass to Add() (I'm only interested in mail items). I've guessed a few of the obvious ones (ReceivedTime, SenderEmailAddress, To, Subject, Body, EntryID). I was hoping to be able to get the (plain text) body of each email, but trying to add the property Body doesn't seem to work. Is it impossible to get Body as a column, or is it just under a different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page [Unsupported Properties in a Table Object or Table Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147580.aspx) says that Body should work for the first 255 bytes. That didn't work for me, but even if it did, that's not what I want. Thus, I get the `EntryID` property, then use `mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(entryId, Type.Missing)` to get the `MailItem` object, and get the (entire) plain-text body from `MailItem.Body`.